# c# WPF change color of specific text in messagebox

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello guys as the title says. How can I change the color of specific text in the `messagebox`. Specifically I'm using `MessageBoxResult`. Im using `C# WPF`.
I attached an image for more detailed info. thank you

[image: Attached Item]

Comment: Any efforts so far?

Comment: You have to create your own MessageBox using CustomControl

Comment: I tried searching sir @bit, but i did not find solution so i posted here, maybe sir Azaz ul Haq already answered. Thank you and have a great day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with MessageBox class, you have to design a custom dialog to achieve what you are looking for.  Message box is merely a prefabricated modal dialog box that displays a text message to a user.

Comment: Ok sir, So it is not possible, thank you so much for the info.